# get total hours from nsdate

Tags: ios, nsdate

I'm just looking for a method that calculates the total hours from nsdate (does the same as the TotalHours method in .net)

example : 11:30:30 -> 11.5 hours

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the hour and minute separated with `NSDateComponents`.

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:(NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit) fromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSInteger hour = [components hour];
NSInteger minute = [components minute];
```

Then use this to find the sum.

```
double totalHours = ((double)hour + (double)minute/60);
```