# iOS NSDate to Single Digits

Tags: ios, objective-c, view, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am working on an app and I have this code:

```
NSDateFormatter *clockFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[clockFormat setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
self.clockLabel.text = [clockFormat stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
[self performSelector:@selector(updateClockLabel) withObject:self afterDelay:1.0];
```

I created a view with subviews to create a LCD type clock display and I want to hide the correct subviews corresponding to the clockLabel. I created arrays of each view (digit), now how do I tell the views that if the first h in hh:mm is 1, hide these subviews to make an LCD "1" in the view.

Simply, how do I access each digit of hh:mm?

Comment: Please, look at answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2927028/how-do-i-get-hour-and-minutes-from-nsdate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12750626/get-total-hours-from-nsdate

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSRange to get substrings. Use `NSRangeMake(location,length)`. To get an NSString of the first character of `self.clockLabel.text`. You can say say

```
NSString *firstHourDigit = [self.clockLabel.text substringWithRange:NSRangeMake(0,1)];
```